# Access flask application context from within greenlet

Tags: flask, gevent, greenlets

I have a flask-script command that spawns a long sequence of greenlets. The problem is, these greenlets are unable to access my app context. I get a 
"> failed with RuntimeError" at all times (accessing app.logger, per example). Suggestions?

On of my attempts:
    spawn(method, app, arg1, arg2)

```
def spawn(app, arg1, arg2):
    with app.app_context():
        app.logger.debug('bla bla') # doesn't work
        ... do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: below gives you access to the `request` object, but not the `current_app`, probably not what you are searching for.

You are probably looking for `flask.copy_current_request_context(f)` which is documented here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.copy_current_request_context

Example:

```
import gevent
from flask import copy_current_request_context

@app.route('/')
def index():
    @copy_current_request_context
    def do_some_work():
        # do some work here, it can access flask.request like you
        # would otherwise in the view function.
        ...
    gevent.spawn(do_some_work)
    return 'Regular response'
```

Comment: Thanks Emeier. Actually, I had to overwrite the __call__ method from my flask-script command in order to make things work. I probably made a big fuss for too little xP~

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a copy of the relevant info from the request, e.g.

```
import gevent

@app.route('/')
def index():
    def do_some_work(data):
        # do some work here with data
        ...
    data = request.get_json()
    gevent.spawn(do_some_work, data)
    return 'Regular response'
```

Comment: If anything in `do_some_work` requires application context, this will not work. That includes any database access if you are using flask-sqlalchemy, flask-pymongo, etc.